# C strncmp return 1

Tags: c, gcc, ubuntu-12.04

I was trying to implement my own strncmp in native C, then I started doing some tests like this one

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

printf("%d\n", strncmp("test\200", "test\0", 6));
```

And the return of strncmp in this particular situation was 1; can anyone explain me why?

I'm pretty sure it's because \200 exceeds default ASCII, then I implemented a condition that if the char is not between 0 and 127 I would return 1, is this right?

Comment: Nobody can say this. The implementation of `strcmp` does not matter as long as it returns 0 if the strings are equal, > 0 if s1 > s2, and < 0 if s1 < s2. The value does not need to have a meaning.

Comment: 1) strcmp only takes 2 arguments. 2) "Positive value if lhs appears after rhs in lexicographical order. " . So is \200 or \0 first? Seems right to me.

Comment: Remember that C strings are null terminated. That `\0` is no-op.

Comment: Your strings do _not_ match, so `strcmp` returns non-zero. You are comparing: `'t' 'e' 's' 't' 0x80 0x00` against `'t' 'e' 's' 't' 0x00`and the 5th elements (index 4) compare 0x80 against 0x00. You could use _any_ non-zero byte at that location in the first string (e.g. 'x' or 0x20) and that will trigger a mismatch. Also, the strings have lengths of 6 and 5 respectively, so they will [again] fail to match. And, `strcmp` takes only _two_ arguments. It is `strncmp` that takes 3, and with a 3rd arg of 6, you'd _still_ have a mismatch

Comment: I meant strNcmp, sorry guys.

Comment: If it helps, you may want to consider that the `\200` byte is an octal value, and that it is YOU who is trying to hoodwink the language to treat an unsigned octal value as a signed char...

Comment: The real question is, "Why reinvent `strcmp()?`"

Comment: Your code must handle 8-bit characters.  It must treat the byte values as if they are `unsigned char` and produce the correct answer.  The world of the 1980s is long gone.

Comment: The bytes of your 2nd string are actually `test\0\0`. The `0` marks the end of a string in C, thus your test is `strncmp("test\200","test",6)` (5 would be enough). Now the 1st string is equal to the 2nd and has 1 more char, thus 1 is returned (and anyway, 200 > 0)

Answer (score 1):

Per man page:

> int strncmp(const char *s1, const char *s2, size_t n);
> ...
> strcmp() returns an integer indicating the result of the comparison, as follows:
> • 0, if the s1 and s2 are equal;
> • a negative value if s1 is less than s2;
> • a positive value if s1 is greater than s2.

The numeric value is otherwise undefined.

This means `\200` is greater than `\0` (end of string) which more concisely would be written as:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("%d\n", strncmp("\200", "", 1));
    return 0;
}
```